# Regex loop and number phone

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my code but I can't display the other numbers because I have indexed [0] and I don't know how I can display the other numbers.

```
Example string: "Hello, you can contact me at 0744224422 or 0192234422."

Result code : "Hello, you can contact me at <span>0744224422</span> or <span>0744224422</span>."
```

On this example: my code will replace "0192234422" by 0744224422 "which is logical" but I would like it to display 0192234422... How can I do it ?

Thanks

```
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.message > div > .chat');
    for (let index = 0; index < selector.length; index++) {
        if (selector[index].innerText) {
            let text = selector[index].innerText;
            const regex = /(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}/gim;
            if (text.match(regex).length) {
                const newTexte = ` <span>${text.match(regex)[0].trim()}</span> `;
                selector[index].innerHTML = text.replace(regex, newTexte); 
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `$` replacement character of the *replace* function, it will put the right text in there.  Rather than `trim` just put parentheses around the non-whitespace portion of your regular expression and effectively let the capturing group become the trim operation.

```js
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.message > div > .chat');
    for (let index = 0; index < selector.length; index++) {
        if (selector[index].innerText) {
            let text = selector[index].innerText;
            const regex = /(\d[\s-]?)?([\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4})/gim;
            if (text.match(regex).length) {
                const newTexte = ` <span class="red">$2</span> `;
                selector[index].innerHTML = text.replace(regex, newTexte); 
            };
        }
    }
```

```css
.red {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <div>
    <div class="chat">Hello, you can contact me at 0744224422 or 0192234422.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to try to call attention to the difference in the regular expressions below: (because I added one set of parentheses)

```
/(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}/gim
            (                                                   )
/(\d[\s-]?)?([\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4})/gim;
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't like the approach of replacing with surrounding space that was used in the original question because it inserts a space before the trailing period.  But that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two separate instances of the selector? If not then the selector.length is only 1 which is why only the first number is shown. You can edit the html to have more than one instance of the selector (and style with display: inline so that it doesn't line break onto a new line) EX:

```js
let selector = document.querySelectorAll('.message > div > .chat');
    for (let index = 0; index < selector.length; index++) {
        if (selector[index].innerText) {
            let text = selector[index].innerText;
            const regex = /(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}/gim;
            if (text.match(regex).length) {
                const newTexte = ` <span>${text.match(regex)[0].trim()}</span> `;
                selector[index].innerHTML = text.replace(regex, newTexte); 
            };
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="message">
  <div>
    <p class="chat" style="display:inline">
      Hello, you can contact me at 0744224422 or </p>
    <p class="chat" style="display:inline">0192234422</p>
    <!-- add more numbers as needed in another <p class="chat" style="display:inline" ></p>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, but I would just like to add a `<span></span>` (or more) when a phone number is written in the string..